# Get datetime in a database and show it in 3 separate fields in dreamweaver [ year, month, day ]

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, dreamweaver

I am using xampp for my database and dreamweaver for my website.

**Fields in database :**

```
field 1 = id       : int, primarykey and auto increment

field 2 = name     : text

field 3 = birthday : datetime
```

**example data :**

```
id: 01

name : jhon

birthday : 2000-06-01
```

In dreamweaver I have 2 textfields and 3 select/list :

One textfield for id, one textfield for name, one select/list for year in birthday, one for month and one for day.

I can get the id and name from the database and show it by using php echo.

### How do I show the birthday separately in each select/list year, month and day ?

Comment: what u have tried?

Comment: @MayankVadiya i have tried using 'php echo "$data[birthday]" ' in dynamic select/list, but the select/list box still showing the default value instead of the year of the birthday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you retrieve the datetime variable, you'll have it in a string similar to this:

```
$datetime = '2000-06-01';
```

If you have already gotten to that point, then do the following:

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $datetime);

echo "year = ".$year."<br>";//year = 2000
echo "month = ".$month."<br>";//month = 06
echo "day = ".$day."<br>";//day = 01
```

Hope I could help! :)

Comment: Its works !!! but my select/list box only showing when the value have two digit, like 16, or 25. 01- 09 seems to be not showing in my select/list box. even if i change all one digit value into two digit (1 into 01, 2 into 02,etc) in my selectlist box, it still not showing the value i want.

Comment: @EinHazard So I don't know what code you used in your select/list box in order to see what the problem is. Also, if this answer solved the specific problem previously, please accept it with a check mark so that future users know what solution worked for you :). You can also edit your post and include your select/list box code at the bottom and I'll see if I can find the problem.

Comment: actually this is my first time in stackoverflow, i dont know how to make a dark box full of coding like you all do, so sorry that i cant show my coding since when i copy/paste my code in the question box, the text is gone...

Comment: @EinHazard If you look at my Answer, on the left side there is a number with an arrow above and an arrow below. Under the arrow below, if you move your mouse close, there is a gray check mark. If you click the checkmark, it turns green. That is how you accept an answer in stackoverflow. Also if you liked an answer, you can also click the ^ arrow.

Comment: haha... sure, i solved the problem mostly because of your solution after all... thanks

Comment: @EinHazard no problem dude :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want do this operation in SQL, in MySQL you have a fonction called DATE_FORMAT() to customize the format of you date

so to split the date into 3 fields (aliases of the orginal record), use a query like that :

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  DATE_FORMAT(birthday,'%d') AS birth_day,
  DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%m') AS birth_month,
  DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%Y') AS birth_year
FROM the_name_of_your_table
```

You will find on this URL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format all the parameters accepted by this functions and returns format.

Hope that help you.